# Printing in a Ruby Thread while waiting for input generates weird output

Tags: ruby, multithreading, printing, newline, output

So I was working in Ruby and the idea was to constantly reprint a set of strings over itself until a key is pressed. This is my code for that

```
frame = 
"aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd"

thread = Thread.new do
    while(true)
        print frame
        sleep(0.5)
    end

end

thread.run

begin
  system("stty raw -echo")
  str = STDIN.getc
ensure
  system("stty -raw echo")
end

thread.kill
```

When this code executes, it generates the output

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
ddddaaaa
        bbbb
            cccc
                ddddaaaa
                        bbbb
                            cccc
                                ddddaaaa
                                        bbbb
                                            cccc
                                                ddddaaaa
                                                        bbbb
                                                            cccc
                                                                dddd
```

Obviously, you would think that it should produce

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
```

repeating until a key is pressed, and I can't figure out why it doesn't. Thoughts?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you could pare this down to a simpler example. Further, for the best help, you should provide a fully functioning standalone example exhibiting the problem, not just a subset of the code needed to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry. The idea is that I'm printing a series of frames in ascii back and forth that I can stop on a keystroke. It works, but it completely blows away any newline characters in any of the frames. I'll throw together a simpler example soon.

Comment: See my 'answer' showing that what you describe seems not to be a problem. You'll need a pared down test case, or to describe the OS and Ruby version where the code fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code works as expected for me, including printing newlines. If it works correctly for you, then you have misidentified the cause of your problems.

```
swivel = Thread.new do
  loop do
    print "Hello\nWorld"
    sleep 0.5
  end
end.run

puts "Press Enter to Stop"
str = STDIN.gets

swivel.kill
```

---

**Edit**: When you call `stty raw -echo`, any `\n` characters will only go down a line. You need `\r\n` to first go to the front of a line, and then `\n` to go down to the next line. Presumably your source file is saved with "unix line endings" (`\n` only), and so the newlines literally embedded in your string are not sufficient.

Comment: This code provides a fix to my problem, but I'm still curious as to why the modified example I provided above acts as it does. I've marked your answer as correct since it fixes my problem though.

Comment: @SSEMember Answer updated with sort of information on your edited question.